# sorting by code

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, sorting

I have food categories in db like:

```
 category_id | parent_id |  code  |               name               
-------------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------
           1 |           |        | root
           2 |         1 | 1      | vegetables
          11 |         1 | 10     | seeds
          54 |        11 | 10.1   | sunflower seeds
          12 |         1 | 11     | sugar and candy
          22 |         2 | 1.1    | frozen vegetables
```

I want to sort it either by `code` in query or programmatically using parent_id (in POJO after mapping). Effect should be like this:

```
1
---1.1
------1.1.1
------1.1.2
------1.1.3
---1.2
2
3
---3.1
...
```

I already tried `ORDER BY code` but I received records ordered like: 1, 10.1.1, 11, 1.1.1
Should I try to sort it in query or when it's mapped. Maybe are there already interfaces/other utils in java for this purpose?

`code` type is character varying and I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: Can you paste your query? Query shld be sufficient for this. Also clarify on "code in query or programmatically using parent_id" , you want to sort by code or parentid?

Comment: what is code's data type? string or number?

Comment: Has to be a string as he has `1.1.1` listed as one of the outputs.

Comment: @loki by sorting using parent_id I mean that in java object of Category class there is a method getParent() (based on parent_id).

Comment: What i am not able to understand is, at query level you want to sort by code but at java level by parent_is. Whys is this so? Why can't you sort once at query level itself?

Comment: You might want to check out the `ltree` data type too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. This sorts by parent_id because sorting on a varchar column like your `code` column is not that easy due to the mismatch between character ordering and numeric ordering.

```
with recursive cat_tree as (
   select category_id, parent_id, name, array[category_id] as sort, category_id::text as path
   from category
   where parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.category_id, c.parent_id, c.name, p.sort||c.category_id, p.path||'.'||c.category_id
   from category c
     join cat_tree p on p.category_id = c.parent_id
)
select category_id, parent_id, path, name
from cat_tree
order by sort;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fab3c/1

Comment: perfect! It's all I can say :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Postgres can do hierarchical / recursive queries which allow you to actually treat your data as tree structure. [This tutorial](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/29/hierarchical-queries-in-postgresql/) has a very nice explanation of that. In fact, the example picked there is very close to what you want to do.